# How do I add a column in PowerBI that evaluates the difference of Latest End time and Earliest Start Time from a large dataset?

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am new to PowerBI. I am trying to make a report of the number of days consumed for a test to complete. There is a large fleet of tests that are run across a week and I would like to subtract the Earliest Start Time from the Latest End time, excluding Saturdays and Sundays and then display the result as a new column next to the Latest actual end as shown in the picture below.

[image: PowerBI Screenshot]

Pardon for any errors above. The data was fetched from a SQL Server using a query (if that helps). Thank you.

Comment: As a measure or as a calculated column?

Comment: Are you saying that if the test crosses a weekend, the hours in the weekend (48) shouldn't be counted?

Comment: @Alexis - As a Measure, please.

Comment: @NIck - That's correct :)

Comment: I would also like to add that the columns "Earliest Start Time" and "Latest End Time" are not columns in the database, I aggregated them in Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

query in sql server

```
select 
  *
  --number of days 
  ,DATEDIFF (day,[Earrliest startTime], [Latest actualend]) diffday
from TestTable
--excluding Saturdays and Sundays
where datepart(weekday,[Earrliest startTime]) not in (6,7) 
  and datepart(weekday,[Latest actualend]) not in (6,7)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bfe5e/9/0)

Hope it help you :-)

Comment: Thank you. I got a Msg 147 in SQL on trying to implement this. I will continue to try :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a New Table `DateTable` to be your calendar table.

```
DateTable = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Add a weekday column so you can filter out weekends.

```
Weekday = WEEKDAY(DateTable[Date])
```

Now you can create a measure that counts the days between your first and last day:

```
DayCount = COUNTX(DateTable,
               IF(DateTable[Date]+1 > MIN(StartEnd[startTime]) &&
                  DateTable[Date]+1 < MAX(StartEnd[acutalend]) &&
                  NOT(DateTable[Weekday] IN {1,7}),
                  1, BLANK()))
```

The `+1` are there to give you end of day rather than beginning of day.